# Appsettings.json get string with two programs running

Tags: c#, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm using run and debugging from VS Code, but when i run both projects API and MVC, give me error.

> An exception of type 'System.ArgumentNullException' occurred in Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.dll but was not handled in user code: 'Value cannot be null.'

**My code:**

```
options.UseSqlServer(Configuration["Data:UCASAppDatabase:ConnectionString"]));
```

This happen after i run both projects using debug, but if i create appsettings outside API work, but what i want is work with appsettings inside API.

How i get string from appsettings.json, without creating new appsettings.json?

[image: Project Folders]

Comment: Most likely you need to click on appsettings.json, go to properties -> Copy to Output Directory -> Copy if newer

Comment: Copy  `appsettings.json` to the root directory of the project.

Comment: @TanvirArjel but it’s not supposed to be better to work with the files defined for each project? without having to change places

Comment: my teacher talk about it when i try put views from mvc on root directory

Comment: From the screenshot API and MVC appear to be separate projects. Is there any reason they are separate? I'd be tempted to merge them in to a single project.

Comment: Yes, because i use mvc to get data from api, they are different projects

Comment: Why! This doesn't seem right! MVC controllers would normally serve up a mixture of HTML and JavaScript, with API controllers serving JSON or XML to JavaScript running in the browser. I would never have an MVC app use an API app in this way, unless it was a third party API.

Comment: I'm no one to talk about it xD, but my teacher told me to do that to the beginning. He said using api with mvc is hard and confused.

Comment: Your teacher doesn't appear to understand the subject matter very well! It's easy with ASP.Net Core!

Comment: @phuzi Separating an MVC app from a Web API app has its own benefits - it makes transition to a SPA style app easier in the future, and if all traffic flows through the API then it keeps the business logic centralized there, which means more functionality is present in the API for additional consumers to take advantage of (such as a mobile or desktop app). Just because you don't understand the benefits doesn't mean the approach is invalid.

Comment: @mason, I'd agree but calling the API from the MVC app seems a little redundant if the app is architected properly i.e. move business logic and repository to their own projects, so they can be shared by both API and MVC apps.

Answer (score 1):

It's generally best to keep them separate, but if you really want to use just one, you should be able to add the appsettings.json file as a linked item in the project that doesn't contain the physical file. Use add => existing item, select "Add as Link" from the Add drop-down and select the file(s) you want to add. Make sure their build action is Content + "Copy if Newer" and you should be good to go. You might consider making a solution folder and putting shared resources there so it's more apparent that you have shared resources.

Edit: 
You should be able to manually add if VS Code doesn't have a way through the UI.
Editing the .csproj file and add the content files you need:

```
<ItemGroup> 
    <Content Include="..\Root\appsettings.json" Link="appsettings.json">
        <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </Content>
</ItemGroup>
```

Comment: I know you can do that in Visual Studio, does it work in VS Code too?

Comment: probably not, but you should be able to add the links manually to your .csproj file:
   `<ItemGroup>
      <Content Include="..\Root\appsettings.json" Link="appsettings.json" />
    </ItemGroup>`

Comment: I change my .csproj from api to `<ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore" `Version="3.1.0" />
    `<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer" `Version="3.1.0" />`
    `<Content Include="..\Root\appsettings.json" Link="appsettings.json" /> 
  </ItemGroup>`

Comment: "..\Root\appsettings.json" would be a relative location to your project. you'll need to change it based on where your file resides relative to the project you want it in. Also, I would keep it in it's own `<ItemGroup>` best to not mix item group purposes.